# How do you enclose highlighted words in a textarea with some tags, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, say I wanted to highlight a block of text in a textarea field and then enclose the text with `<highlight>...</highlight>` tags (e.g. `<highlight>(highlighted text appears here)</highlight>`) by pressing a link -- e.g.:

```
<textarea id="comment-body"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="highlight-words" onclick="highlightWords()">Highlight</a>

function highlightWords(){
   // code for enclosing highlighted text in textarea appears here
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I really have no idea why this is marked as duplicate when the questions and answers are very different. This is one of the strangest things I've seen on StackOverflow. I'm glad I got the answer I wanted before the overzealous moderating closed this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties to find the selected text. This will give you the start and end indexes, which you can use to update the string.

```html
<textarea id="comment-body"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="highlight-words">Highlight</a>
```

```js
$('a.highlight-words').click(function() {
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('comment-body');
  var fullText = document.getElementById('comment-body').value;
  var selectedText;
  var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
  var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
  selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)

  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    var newStr = fullText.substr(0, endPos) + '</highlight>' + fullText.substr(endPos);
    newStr = newStr.substr(0, startPos) + '<highlight>' + newStr.substr(startPos);

    textComponent.value = newStr;
  }
});
```

Demo here: [http://jsfiddle.net/rqy7e0qh/](http://jsfiddle.net/rqy7e0qh/1/)

Comment: That was great!! Works perfectly on the first time. Thank you Andrew!! :)